# Qt: pull a section of image data on the fly

Tags: qt

I have a very large image(10000*10000) and for several reasons I cannot modify it (like chop it into smaller tiles.)

I don't want to display the whole image but a small section of it to improve the GUI efficiency.
But when the user click and drag it around, new part of image will be displayed in the viewport.
So, how could I pull a section of image data on the fly?

Comment: You can take a look at `QPainter::drawPixmap (const QRectF &target, const QPixmap &pixmap, const QRectF &source )`.

Comment: QML or QWidget?  It would be nice if you give us at least one reason why you can't tile the image (especially if the image is in RAM).

Comment: Because of some copyright issues, I am not allowed to modify the image or tile it... I would like to load just the area I required from the hard disk but it need to be fast.

Comment: If the image is a bitmap, without compression than you can easily read only part of the bitmap, but you will have to write some code for it - if it's not a bitmap then you'll have to load whole image into the memory to crop it.

Comment: We need to know what is the format of the image, and, if the format is a container with multiple sub-content formats possible (such as bmp or tiff), what is the particular one used.

Comment: Yes its in tiff format!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall Qt providing any support for working with partial images in case of really high resolutions. Maybe look into [libtiff](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/libtiff.html).

Basically, the image will be composed of either strips or tiles, so you can use the `tiffreadscanline()` or `tiffreadencodedstrip()` respectively to load portions of the image. The from that you can compose another image with the appropriate resolution for your viewport.

Alternatively, you could take a look at the `QTiffHandler` class, it is a private class in Qt so it is not directly accessible, but you could just copy it and if necessary modify the source to expose its functionality. Internally it uses `libtiff` as well.